Hide image if another one is opened, vice versa
I'm have code for two images (Image1, Image2) that both open if two other images are clicked, with onclick and a Java part at the end, like so:
<table style="background-color: #ebebeb; border-color: #a9e0ff; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0rem;" cellpadding="10" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: #ebebeb;">

            <td><a href="link to game1 when the image is clicked" alt="Game1" target="blank" onclick="AfficherCacher('Image1')"> <img src="the image clicked to open Game1+Image1.jpg" width="1689" height="955" class="img-fluid atto_image_button_text-bottom"></a><br></td>
           <td><a href="link to game2 when the image is clicked" alt="Game2" target="blank" onclick="AfficherCacher('Image2')"> <img src="the image clicked to open Game2+Image2.jpg" width="1689" height="955" class="img-fluid atto_image_button_text-bottom"></a><br></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

then
<table style="background-color: #ebebeb; border-color: #a9e0ff; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0rem;" cellpadding="10" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: #ebebeb;">
            <td>
                <div id="Image1" style="display: none; border: solid 4px #764184; border-radius: 20px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 10px;" bis_skin_checked="1">
                    <ul>

            <td>
                <div id="Image1">
                    <ul>
                        <img src="Image1.jpg">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
</table>
  <table style="background-color: #ebebeb; border-color: #a9e0ff; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0rem;" cellpadding="10" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: #ebebeb;">
            <td>
                <div id="Image2">
                    <ul>
                        <img src="Image2.jpg">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>

And then the JavaScript part at the end making it all work:
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        function AfficherCacher(texte) {
            var test = document.getElementById(texte).style.display;
            if (test == "block") {
                document.getElementById(texte).style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(texte).style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        // ]]>
    </script>
</p>

The only thing is that both Image1 and Image2 can be displayed on the page at the same time, which I do not want. I would like for opening Image2 to make Image1 disappear, and for opening Image1 to make Image2 disappear.
I do not know what to use for this.
I have tried inventing "if" conditions, but I am not JavaScript (or CSS) literate, so I'm going in blind, and I'm clearly doing something wrong. I don't know what I'm able to use and what exists/works.
This is basically what it looks like. Both the little "RUSH" and "MOOD" pictures are the images that both redirect to 2 different links in another tab, AND also display the corresponding image below.
In this example, I have clicked the "MOOD" image, which opened the "MOOD video game" in another tab, and opened the "recap for MOOD" below: https://i.sstatic.net/3fLh5.jpg
However, if I then click the "RUSH" image, it will open the "RUSH video game" in another tab (which is good) but also open the "recap for RUSH" below, next to the "recap for MOOD". What I want is only for one or the other to be open, so if I click on the "RUSH" image, the "recap for  MOOD" will disappear, and vice versa.

"code for 2 images (Image1, Image2) that both open if 2 other images are clicked" so there are 4 images? Can you show a working prototype here? Thx


JAVA is not JavaScript. 2. Please click [edit], then click the button marked [<>] and produce a [mcve] with RELEVANT HTML, CSS and JavaScript which does not need to live in a p tag. And please do not use "whatever" since you obviously need something else than "whatever"


Also you have links in your hrefs, so you need to change the AfficherCacher to an event handler and take care of the click. You cannot show and hide things when clicking on something that changes the page unless you use localStorage or similar

Also, don't use JS in a render-blocking manner (disseminated inside your HTML, specially not inside a <p>). <script>s should be ideally placed right before your closing </body> tag, or eventually in <head> using a defer and src attributes.

Also, avoid using <a> (anchor) if what you need is a <button type="button"> or rather none of the mentioned.

Also, alt="Game1" is not a valid <a> attribute; also, should be target="_blank" rel="nofollow"

@RokoC.Buljan They want the a to open something in a new tab

@Mr.Brickowski could you please walk me through how to do that? I don't know how to, but would be happy to.
There are indeed 4 images but the 1rst 2 are not relevant here since they're just used as  points to open the images I do need help with

@RokoC.Buljan I am so, so happy you all are trying to help, but I have never ever coded in my life before (forced to for work), you're quite literary speaking a language that I don't right now!

@RokoC.Buljan My  opens in another tab, but this already works just fine, my only problem is that, when clicking the s (which redirects to a link in another tab, ALSO opens a picture on the first tab), both said pictures can open at the same time, when I only want for one OR the other to open, never both at the same time.

Would it work to add an "if" to the onclick of my existing code with "window.close()"? The only thing is I do not know how to integrate that to my existing code, as I am even less than a "begginer"!

If you only want ONE image be displayed, why not just have ONE image, and alter its image-url on click?

@DavidWeber I'm unsure of how it would be done. I edited my post, adding a link to the screenshot of what it actually looks like, with a more detailed description of what I would want, if that helps. Again, so sorry, I have never coded before in my life.

Step 1: Rename AfficherCacher(texte) to displayRecap(recapToDisplay). Step 2: Do this in this function: Hide ALL elements first by setting them display:none. Then give one element display:block to show it.

You can delegate using data-attributes.
I see you want to open in a new window, so you need the target="_blank"
Links to do not have alt like images do. You can however use title.
Lastly you use table for the images in what I gave the ID of imageTable. I am not sure why you need table, div and ul for image, when you in principle can have just the images


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const linkTable = document.getElementById('linkTable');
  const imageDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#imageTable div');
  linkTable.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('a');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a link
    imageDivs.forEach(div => {
      const id = div.id;
      const tgtId = tgt.dataset.target;
      div.hidden = tgtId !== id;
    })  
  });
});
<table id="linkTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="link to game1 when the image is clicked" title="Game1" data-target="image1" target="_blank"><img src="https://placehold.co/1689x955?text=Open+Image1" width="1689" height="955" class="img-fluid atto_image_button_text-bottom"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="link to game2 when the image is clicked" title="Game2" data-target="image2" target="_blank"><img src="https://placehold.co/1689x955?text=Open+Image2" width="1689" height="955" class="img-fluid atto_image_button_text-bottom"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<table id="imageTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="image1" hidden>
          <ul>
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1689x955?text=Image1">Image 1
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="image2" hidden>
          <ul>
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1689x955?text=Image2">Image 2
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>




I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it's not working. Image1 is now displayed even when the first image has not been clicked, and clicking on the second one still opens both images at the same time (aaaaah)

As you can see it works here. I cannot help you since with the rudimentary HTML you provided, it works with the changes I made. Did you add the data-attributes and give the tables IDs?

Another possible method to show or hide is using a predefined class and adding it dynamically to the image.
Look at this example:


function showImage(imgId) {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.pImg img');
  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.classList.toggle('hidden', image.id !== imgId);
  });
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pBtn button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pBtn img {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}

.pImg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.pImg img {
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<div class="pBtn">
  <button onclick="showImage('img1')">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6vwMfQj.png" width="320" height="180" />
  </button>

  <button onclick="showImage('img2')">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Ori_crop_320_x_180_looking_SW.JPG" width="320" height="180" />
  </button>
</div>

<div class="pImg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6vwMfQj.png" width="320" height="180" id="img1" class="hidden" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Ori_crop_320_x_180_looking_SW.JPG" width="320" height="180" id="img2" class="hidden" />
</div>




Use toogle instead of an if/else statement to use add/remove. It specifically exist for this very case

Thank you both. The only thing is: I'm afraid this wouldn't work if my buttons were images instead of >A< and >B<? Or am I allowed to define the button as an image? But, in that case, how am I allowed to integrate it in the place of >A< and >B<? Can I add "img src=image1.jpg instead?

@RichterMégane I've edited the answer with the image as the button, and implemented the use of toggle instead  of if/else.

@TanishqS Thank you so very much. It is not working, though, but I think it's because I'm not integrating it where it should be.
Where am I supposed to integrate the function? It's appearing above the buttons as plain text, somehow.
The picture also do not show when the buttons are clicked now T_T

From what I can see from your code, you've put <script> inside a  <p> tag. You must put it directly inside the <body> tag instead. See this
